# MPlayer forward/rewind speed

Tags: mplayer

Is it possible to configure how far MPlayer will skips when I press the arrow keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the input.conf file, find the lines for "(UP|DOWN|RIGHT|LEFT) seek" and adjust the values for each one.